# Number theory problem- prime represented as sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if the prime $p=x^2+y^2$ and $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{10}$, then $5|xy$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Look at the equation $p=x^2+y^2$ modulo $5$; what are the possibilities for $x^2$ and $y^2$ modulo $5$?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out! It slipped me that I can write 4(mod 5) as -1(mod 5)

Answer (score 1):

If $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod {10}$ then $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$. The only quadratic residues mod $5$ are $0,1$ and $-1$. So $x^2+y^2\equiv 1 \pmod 5\iff \{x^2,y^2\}=\{0,1\} \pmod 5$ and $x^2+y^2\equiv -1 \pmod 5\iff \{x^2,y^2\}=\{0,-1\} \pmod 5$, so one between $x$ and $y$ must be multiple of $5$ and so $xy\mid 5$

Answer (score 0):

If $5\not\mid xy,$ then $5\not\mid x$ and $5\not\mid y,$ so $x^2, y^2\equiv \pm 1 \mod 5,$

so $p=x^2+y^2\equiv \pm2$ or $0\pmod 5,$ so $p\not\equiv\pm1\mod10$.

Comment: I proved the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)